# How do you verify an email via javascript or django?

Tags: javascript, django

How can I verify that the users email address belongs to them?  All of the answers I have found are verification ensuring the email is an actual email, but I want to verify that the email belongs to the user signing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a confirmation email. A quick google search brings up many results.
One such result: https://github.com/mfogel/django-simple-email-confirmation

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was just searching the wrong things.

Comment: Happens to us all